# EntityFramework. Selecting parent objects whose grandchildren appear in int array of Ids

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Given the following entities

Brokers / AccountTypes / ExecutionOptions

Brokers have many AccountTypes

AccountTypes have many ExecutionOptions

Given an int array of ExecutionOptions Ids

how would I select all Brokers that Contain AccountTypes that contain ExecutionOptions whos Ids appear in my array of incoming ints?

Comment: Use the answer to your previous question. Just continue with `Any(x => x.Y.Any(y => y.Z.Any(...` until you hit the collection to apply `Contains`.

Comment: that simple huh? If you want to write that up as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can start with ExecutionOptions, filter by id, then join upwards through all the tables until you reach Brokers. Only Brokers with existing relationships between the tables will be found, otherwise the Joins will filter them out.

Comment: I dont think that would work in my case. ExecutionOptions is one of many different GrandChildren entities that I need to filter by, so I have to work down from Broker. The comment supplied by Ivan Stoev in the original question provided a workable method